# Bad to Detach AWS EBS volume before Unmounting?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, disk-volume

I've attached a snapshot of another volume to a test Instance on AWS.  Both instances run Ubuntu Lucid.

I've tried to unmount the test instance but it's claiming that the device is busy.  I think this may be due to the fact that I copied the root volume from the other instance, so there are dupes of the bash executables.

Is there now a relationship between my real volume and the snapshotted clone?  Can I just terminate the test instance, or will that corrupt the volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

terminating the snapshot will in no way affect the original volume.

You might try `lsof | grep /snapshot/mount/point` to try and find any open files, if you still want to try to unmount it.  But really, a proper umount will only serve to make sure files in the snapshot are safe.  If you don't care about the snapshot, kill the sucker!

Comment: I love the enthusiasm, thanks James.  The sucker is dead!

Comment: Thanks.  You should upvote whenever you find an answer helpful :)